# É válido usar a palavra "mercar"? Qual a sua origem?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, regionalismo, acentos-ou-sotaques

Ouvia muitas vezes os meus vizinhos utilizarem a palavra "mercar"  equivalente a  "comprar". Possivelmente um regionalismo, ou mais alguém usa?

Qual a sua origem?
Ainda é correto utilizar?

Exemplo
"Merquei um carro"

Comment: De acordo com Houaiss, “mercar”, que tem sentido de comprar para revender, vem do latim “*mercare*” e o supino desse verbo latino, “marcatum”, deu origem ao português “mercado”. Então, “mercar” em si não é um regionalismo, mas é pouco usado com tal sentido. O Houaiss também diz que “mercar” pode significar comprar, então, usá-lo assim errado não é. Em relação à formalidade dessa acepção, não tenho como te dizer com certeza, mas como o Aulete diz que esse uso é sentido figurado e nenhum dicionário que vi diz ser informal ou regional, ACHO que é formal suficiente para usar na prova.

Comment: Com a edição ficou mais adequado.